# Data is not inserted in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

(Yes, the table names are silly... I'm just messing about)

```
CREATE TABLE  `habitat`.`habit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When I try to do the following sql statement, only 0 shows up in content:

```
INSERT into habit
                            (content, user_id)
                            VALUES (content = 'this is some habit', user_id = 2)
```

Comment: arr someone delete this, I just saw  my stupid mistake

Comment: so respond with your solution and accept or accept John's answer (which is probably what you just figured out)

Comment: I pretty sure even at Rep=1 you can delete your own posts

Answer (score 2):

Basically you do not need to include the "columnName = value" in the VALUES portion of an insert statement.  It should look like this.

```
INSERT INTO habit (
  content, 
  user_id)
VALUES (
  'this is some habit', 
  2)
```